# How to add functions on randomly generated numbers

Tags: javascript, function, math

Is it possible to add a function on randomly generated numbers. For example I used `getRndInteger(min, max)`, `Math.floor()` and `Math.random()` to generate random numbers, and within those numbers you want to add function to see which of those generated numbers is the biggest. I was thinking maybe it was possible to put each randomized number in array and use `Math.max()` on them, but I'm not quite sure how you put those numbers in a function that for example on click, you see the generated numbers and result(the biggest number of them all) underneath it. I mainly want to know if it's even possible and if so, how. I'd be super thankful!

So I specifically want to use a random number from -35 to 76 including -35 and 76. I made a button that on click shows the randomized number. Another problem to me is, I'm not sure how to add a randomized number one after another instead of adding new one on click. (Haha sorry if it's a super newbie problem). Then I put an id on paragraph that displays the answer. And I was thinking to use the `document.getElementById("")` for the `Math.max.apply()` and make another paragraph with another ID that displays the answer.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = getRndInteger(-35,76)">Click Me</button>

Chosen number:
<p id="result"></p>

Biggest number:
<p id="result2"> </p>

<script>
    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

</script>

<script>
       Array.max = function(document.getElementById("result");) {
        return Math.max.apply(document.getElementById"result");
    };

</script>
```

When I put `.getElementById()` in `Math.max.apply()` as an array, even on click, java script no longer loads randomized number. Maybe you have to add id to the answers or something, I'm all out of ideas here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'd also like if I'd still use `Math.max()` to do this and avoid any overly complicated codes to understand the issue and use the answer in the future codes. Thank you loads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the previously generated maximum number to be able to determine that the currently generated number is higher than it. See snippet to get an idea.

```js
(() => {
  let max = null;
  const range = {
    min: -35,
    max: 76
  };
  const result = document.querySelector("#result");
  const maxResult = document.querySelector("#resultMax");
  const allNrs = document.querySelector("p#all");

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    const someRandomNumber = getRndInteger(range.min, range.max);
    result.textContent = someRandomNumber;
    max = max && someRandomNumber > max 
      ? someRandomNumber 
      : max 
        ? max 
        : someRandomNumber;
    maxResult.textContent = max;
    allNrs.textContent += ` ${someRandomNumber} `;
  }

  function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
})();
```

```css
#all {
  max-width: 400px
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</p>

Random number:
<span id="result"></span>
<br>Biggest number until now:
<span id="resultMax"></span>

<div>
  <br>All numbers until now:
  <p id="all"></p>
</div>
```